# Can doInBackground in an AsyncTask potentially cause a race condition?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Does the return of a result from the doInBackground method on AsyncTask to the UI have the potential to cause unexpected race conditions? Using 'get' can make the UI wait for the computation to return the result, but that seems to defeat the objective on running a task in background.

Relevant documentation:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doInBackground runs on another thread, so of course it can cause a race condition-  anytime you have two threads, or a thread and asynchronous events incoming you can have a race condition.  You always have to code to avoid them.  However the return of values from doInBackground to onPostExecute will not, so you do have a safe way of passing data between the threads without a race.

Comment: Thanks, I thought/hoped that returning values to onPostexecute would avoid a race, but I was uncertain. Thank you for responding so quickly. I will accept you answer after 4 minute time delay.